How can I import an .xlsx file in jupyter?
I need to import Database.xlsx in jupyter and be able to work on it with sql commands.
I'm using this code:
!pip install pandas==1.3.3

import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Initialize Spark session with Arrow disabled
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ExcelToSpark") \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "false") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Read the Excel file using Pandas
pdf = pd.read_excel('/home/jovyan/Database.xlsx', sheet_name='DB')

# Convert Pandas DataFrame to PySpark DataFrame
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('DB')

which is not working and gives me the following error message

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_222/4258738796.py in ?()
10 # Read the Excel file using Pandas
11 pdf = pd.read_excel('/home/jovyan/Database.xlsx', sheet_name='DB')
12
13 # Convert Pandas DataFrame to PySpark DataFrame
---> 14 sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
15 sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('DB')
/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in ?(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
887         except Exception:
888             has_pandas = False
889         if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
890             # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
--> 891             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
892                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema
893             )
894         return self._create_dataframe(
/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in ?(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
432                         "has been set to false.\n  %s" % str(e)
433                     )
434                     warn(msg)
435                     raise
--> 436         converted_data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
437         return self._create_dataframe(converted_data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in ?(self, pdf, schema, timezone)
470                                 copied = True
471                             pdf[field.name] = s
472             else:
473                 should_localize = not is_timestamp_ntz_preferred()
--> 474                 for column, series in pdf.iteritems():
475                     s = series
476                     if should_localize and is_datetime64tz_dtype(s.dtype) and s.dt.tz is not None:
477                         s = _check_series_convert_timestamps_tz_local(series, timezone)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in ?(self, name)
5985         ----------
5986         datetime : bool, default False
5987             If True, convert to date where possible.
5988         numeric : bool, default False
-> 5989             If True, attempt to convert to numbers (including strings), with
5990             unconvertible values becoming NaN.
5991         timedelta : bool, default False
5992             If True, convert to timedelta where possible.
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

can please somebody help?
thank you in advance

A couple of asides on the first line:  That version of Pandas is really old at this point and unless you are pinning everything that is going to lead to potential problems interacting with more current packages/Python. More importantly, you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter the magic install command. Use %pip install pandas==1.3.3. The magic pip command variation was added in 2019 to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook. The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. ...

 See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

The issue you are asking about is already well-covered on StackOveflow, see here and here.

This question is similar to: Databricks: Issue while creating spark data frame from pandas. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
